# Cannot see Schema.ObjectId in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema, objectid

I create a Collection in Mongodb as this image 
[Mongo Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuTLF.png)

And my HTML form: i.stack.imgur.com/zH12g.png

And my controller: i.stack.imgur.com/GhrgX.png

I can create this document, but in this document I can see my Schema.ObjectId (termParrent). Is this wrong? Or I miss something?

This is my document after create [Document Mongo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ5uV.png)

Sorry, i can post more than 2 link.
Thanks all.

Comment: you can see `_id` instead of `id`

Comment: When I console.log(termParrentFind.id) or console.log(termParrentFind._id) i will see this ID, but i can see this id in mongo document.

Comment: can you try `Schema.Types.ObjectId`  instead of `Schema.ObjectId`?

Comment: Please **do not use images for code** and post all relevant code in your question (see how to make a [mcve]). As it is your question is off-topic for SO.